# Android custom notification height

Tags: android

I've got an android app that needs a custom notification. I've got that to work, no problem so far, but I stumbled upon this irritating [warning in the docs](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/custom-notification):

> Caution: When you use a custom notification layout, take special care to ensure that your custom layout works with different device orientations and resolutions. While this advice applies to all UI layouts, it's especially important for notifications because the space in the notification drawer is very restricted. **The height available for a custom notification layout depends on the Android version.** On some versions, collapsed view layouts are limited to as little as 48 dp, heads up view layouts are limited to as little as 88dp, and expanded view layouts are limited to as little as 252 dp.

The bold part is my problem - how do I know which version has which height limit? Does anyone have a clear table or can point me to one?